# Anyway to make an else if run a certain number of times?

Tags: java, if-statement, statements

e.g

```
else if (currentImage == nekoPics[4]) 
currentImage = nekoPics[5];
```

Need this to run twice, so my cat animation scratches twice, before moving to else, this is probably the worst way to do this, but im interested if you can have an else if execute twice without copy pasting

```
else if (currentImage == nekoPics[5]) 
currentImage = nekoPics[4];
```

and changing the indexes cause that just loops and he'll scratch all the time.

Any help is appreciated

edit: entire code

```
private void scratch(){
    for (int i = xPos; i <getWidth()/2; i+=0){
            xPos = getWidth()/2;
            // swap images

            if (currentImage == nekoPics[0]) 
                currentImage = nekoPics[1];
            else if (currentImage == nekoPics[1]) 
                    currentImage = nekoPics[2];
            else if (currentImage == nekoPics[2]) 
                    currentImage = nekoPics[4];
            else if (currentImage == nekoPics[4]) 
                currentImage = nekoPics[5];
            else 
                i+=10;

            repaint();
            pause(150)
```

Comment: Could you provide your entire code?

Comment: You really need to give more context to this - it's impossible to answer usefully at the moment.

Comment: Put the whole if in a while loop??

Comment: Cats never just scratch twice.  Just put it in an infinite loop.

Comment: I am missing your question. Are you looking for [while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) and [for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) statements?

Comment: If you want to be **brave** (emphasis on the word brave), use a `goto` statement.

Answer (score 2):

The whole if-else logic is superfluous. Put the images in an ordered collection (array, list) in the order thy should be shown, like this

```
 Pictures[] seq = new Pictures[] { pic1, pic2, pic3, pic3, pi2, pic4, pic5 };
```

Then go through the collection, or maintain an index that would point to the next picture.

Comment: does this mean the pictures would have to be in order though?

Comment: @user1667456 - By putting them in a certain order in an array, you **define** their order.

Answer (score 0):

I gather you're moving through a sequence of images, so you could do something like this:

```
else if (currentImage == nekoPics[3]) {
    currentImage = nekoPics[4];
    countdown = 5;
} else if (currentImage == nekoPics[4]) {
    currentImage = nekoPics[5];
} else if (currentImage == nekoPics[5]) {
    if (countdown-- > 0)
        currentImage = nekoPics[4];
    else
        currentImage = nekoPics[6];
} else if ...
```

In other words, when transitioning from 3 to 4, set a countdown variable based on how often you want to repeat the `4,5` sequence.

Then transition from `5` to either `4` or `6` based on the countdown.